# Rewrite rule can it be done?

Tags: url-rewriting

Does anyone know how to rewrite something like

```
/index.php?option=com_k2&view=item&id=30:name-of-item
```

to

```
/index.php/name-of-item
```

or maybe

```
/index.php/blog/name-of-item
```

Comment: ... i need solution for this example because i can't quite understand those conditions and code's...

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using a combination of RewriteCond and RewriteRule:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*:(.*)$
RewriteRule ^/index.php /index.php/%1
```

where %1 is the backreference to the group captured in the RewriteCond expression.

Sources:

- http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond
- http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteQueryString

Comment: I tried but not working... Im not to familiar with this so any bit of help is appreciated... Thanks much...